# Appearance and disappearance of an object in an animation

Tags: animation, physics

My question is: how do I make an object (or any other thing, force field in my case) appear in a scene at the certain time during the animation, affect the soft body, and then disappear? Thank you (Note that I don't mean that the objects just visually appear and disappear, but, uhhh... disappear completely with all their properties and effects on other objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the transparency of the object to none in the object material panel and keyframe it. Then turn transparency to full in another part of the timeline and keyframe it.